# ¿Cómo obtener el mayor número de una lista de strings?

Tags: python

```py
listados=['31', '1', '3', '2', '5', '26', '3', '3', '1', '14', '2', '1', 
          '21', '423', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
          '3', '9']
print(max(listados))
```

Me lanza: 9
debería ser 423.
El contenido de la lista `listados` será una variable así que no serviría buscar un mero directamente.

Comment: ¿Y que has probado? ¿Puedes poner tu código?¿Te da algún error o simplemente no muestra el resultado esperado? Hace falta ver tu código para poder ayudarte. Lee [ask] para que veas como editar tu pregunta y que tenga un formato adecuado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu lista es una lista de cadenas (`str`), las cuales se ordenan en función del orden lexicográfico, es decir, en función de los *codepoints unicode* (en Python 3) de los caracteres.

Básicamente se compara el primer caracteres de cada cadena y se ordena según su codepoint, si varias cadenas tienen el mismo primer carácter se compara el segundo y así sucesivamente.

Si tienes "291" y "2123" la cadena mayor es "291". Primero se compara el primer carácter de ambas cadenas, ambas tienen un "2" por lo que se pasa al siguiente, "9" y "1" (U+0039 y U+0031 respectivamente), al ser mayor el "9" se termina la comparaación y la la cadena "291" queda como mayor.

Si no quieres perder el tipo de los elementos de la lista (que sigan siendo cadenas) pero tratarlos como enteros al obtener el máximo, mínimo u ordenarla lo más simple es hacer uso del argumento `key` que tienen `max`, `min`, `sorted` y `list.sort`. Este argumento recibe un objeto `callable` que recibe como argumento cada item del iterable a ordenar y cuyo retorno es usado para tal fin en vez del item en si mismo. En este caso podemos usar el *built-in* `int` (o `float` si algún item tuviera decimales):

```
listados = ['31', '1', '3', '2', '5', '26', '3', '3', '1',
            '14', '2', '1', '21', '423', '2', '0', '0', '0',
            '2', '0', '0', '0', '0','0', '0', '0', '3', '9']
max_item = max(listados, key=int)
```

---

> ```
> >>> max_item
> '423'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que tu array es un array de string y no de números por eso te da 9 como resultado. Tienes que hacer un paso intermedio que es convertir esa lista de string a enteros.

```
listados=['31', '1', '3', '2', '5', '26', '3', '3', '1', '14', '2', '1', 
'21', '423', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
'3', '9']

listadosNumero = [int(num) for num in listados]
print (max(listadosNumero))
```

Y si solo quieres el resultado sería:

```
    listados=['31', '1', '3', '2', '5', '26', '3', '3', '1', '14', '2', '1', 
    '21', '423', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
    '3', '9']
print(max([int(num) for num in listados]))
```

Saludos.